# Join 3 tables using a lookup table, displaying the results in colmns

Tags: t-sql, pivot, rows, transpose

This may be completely obvious and I am just not seeing it.

Sample data here on [SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6bcf5/5/0)

I have 3 tables Expertise, Contacts and Lookup.

The Lookup table joins the Expertise to the relevant contacts (1 expertise to multiple contacts)

Currently the Contacts data is in rows and I need to transpose it to columns (maximum 5 contacts per Expertise).

Was wanting to use PIVOT because I am trying to learn how it works. Of course may not be the best solution for this problem, alternative suggestions welcome.

The result I am looking for would be something like this:

`ExpertiseName    |Name1         |Email1            |Name2       |Email2 etc...`
`Computer Graphics|Karl Henderson|karl@email.com    |Kevin Foster|kevin@...`
`Robotics         |Viginia Lee   |virginia@email.com|Ruby Riviera|...`

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to pivot multiple columns (Name and Email) which isn't quite as straightforward as pivoting just one field.  An easier way to get the results you're looking for is to do something like this:

```
select ExpertiseName,  
    MAX(case when seq = 1 then ContactName end) Name1, 
    MAX(case when seq = 1 then ContactEmail end) Email1, 
    MAX(case when seq = 2 then ContactName end) Name2,
    MAX(case when seq = 2 then ContactEmail end) Email2,  
    MAX(case when seq = 3 then ContactName end) Name3, 
    MAX(case when seq = 3 then ContactEmail end) Email3,  
    MAX(case when seq = 4 then ContactName end) Name4, 
    MAX(case when seq = 4 then ContactEmail end) Email4,  
    MAX(case when seq = 5 then ContactName end) Name5,
    MAX(case when seq = 5 then ContactEmail end) Email5  
from
(
    select ex.ExpertiseId,
          ex.ExpertiseName, ContactName, ContactEmail,
        ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by ex.ExpertiseId order by ex.ExpertiseId) seq 
    from lookup lk
        join Expertise ex on ex.ExpertiseId = lk.ExpertiseId 
        join Contacts ct on ct.ContactId = lk.ContactId
) SourceTable
group by ExpertiseName
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6bcf5/6/0)